# VSE fade in/out options

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I know of four options to fade out a strip in Blender VSE:
1) Cross effect strip to black color strip.
2) Gamma cross effect strip to black color strip.
3) Animate opacity over black color strip (or over nothing).
4) Animate color multiply over black color strip (or over nothing).

Is there any difference in result between these methods? Apart from the ability to fine tune the curve of the transition when keyframes are used (in the case of opacity and multiply)? 
Does the gamma correction make any difference when fading just to black?
Any of them looks "better" (smoother, better quality) then the other?

Comment: Make the source that you are fading a blend texture, then open a Scopes window and set it to waveform. You should see a sloping line from white on one side down to black on the other. Now you can see how the fade works across all values.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am afraid I don't understand you. You mean to make a texture out of the original image sequence that I want to fade? How will that help me? It has no fading. Then you speak of the scope window of the UV/Image editor? Or the just the Luma waveform view mode of the VSE?

Comment: Use a gradient as a test image and the VSE waveform to see the change. This should help you understand the action of each dissolve type.

Comment: I see. Good idea. I will do some testing. Thanks heaps! :)